# What does Fxxx private class name prefix convention came from?

Tags: delphi

In C++/C# the common convention for private class vars is `m_MyPrivateVar`, and I belive "**m_**" stands for "my" (I might be wrong).

In Delphi, private class variables begin with **F**, e.g. FHandle etc.

What does the F means? Foo? :)

Comment: ... field .....

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, are you sure??? :)

Comment: And the m stands for member. Foo isn't actually a word! And m_ is  not the convention in C#.

Comment: @Vlad - See [Object Pascal Style Guide - #Field Naming](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10280#3.3)

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, Thanks! this guide is wonderfull.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Thank you. I did say that "I might be wrong" about the "m_" thing... Cheers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are some naming conventions not to get lost in code.

Here is an example to point out why this is useful.

```
// Types begins with T
TFoo = class
strict private
  // sometimes I saw strict private fields beginning with underscore
  // I like this too 
  _Value : string;
private
  // private class vars are Fields and therefore begins with F
  FValue : string;
  function GetValue : string;
public
  property Value : string read GetValue write FValue;

  // Parameters should NOT begin with P (P is for Pointer) but with A
  // because "i will pass A value" :o)
  function GetSomething( const AValue : string ) : string;
end;

function TFoo.GetValue : string;
begin
  Result := '*' + FValue + '*';
end;    

function TFoo.GetSomething( const AValue : string ) : string;
var
  // IMHO there is no naming convention to Local vars
  // but mine begins with L
  LValue : string;
begin

  LValue { local var } := 
    Value   { property via getter }  + 
    AValue  { parameter } + 
    FValue  { field };

  Result := LValue;
end;
```

Comment: The "A" in parameters came from "Argument".