# Invalid typecast in a procedure

Tags: delphi

my program code keeps giving me problems when compiling. The idea of the program is just to create a procedure that will read textfiles into an array. The button will then display them on a richedit.

Here is the original code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
 Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
 Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls;
type
 ArrNames = array [1..10] of string;
 ArrSales = array [1..10] of integer;
type
 TForm1 = class(TForm)
 btnShowData: TButton;
 redt1: TRichEdit;
 procedure btnShowDataClick(Sender: TObject);
  private

  public
{ Public declarations }
end;
Procedure Showdata;
 var
   Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


 Procedure ShowData;
   var c2u : textfile;
     count : integer;
     aNames : arrNames;
     aSales : arrSales;
   Begin
    If FileExists('data.txt') <> true then
     begin
       Messagedlg('File does not exist', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
       Exit;
   end;
       Count :=0;
       AssignFile(c2u, 'data.txt');
       Reset(c2u);
       While Not EOF(c2u) do
         begin
            Inc(Count);
            readln (c2u, aNames[count]);
            readln (c2u, aSales[count]);
         end;
       Closefile(c2u);
    End;

  procedure TForm1.btnShowDataClick(Sender: TObject);
    var J : integer;
        aNames : arrNames;
        aSales : arrSales;
   begin
     redt1.lines.add(aNames[J] +#9 + 'R' +IntToStr(aSales[J]));
   end;

  end.
```

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using a TStringList -- the "Delphi" way to do this?

Comment: What is the *exact* error message you get?

Comment: Nick's right about using TStringList. Also, you haven't shown us what `ArrNames` is defined as.  Knowing that would help.

Comment: ArrNames is supposed to be an array that contains Names of different Cycle shops. ArrSales is the amount of sales for each shop. The textfile contains the names and the sales. In class, we haven't studied TStringList, so I cant use it in my exam. The exact error message I get is "Invalid Typecast".

Comment: Don't tell us what it's *supposed* to be. Show us what it *is*. Copy and paste the declaration from your code.

Comment: Declaring the arrays in the procedure did work. Is there any reason though why the textfile wont read into the array? The program compiles, but it doesn't show the data of the textfile.

Comment: There's no mentioning of `ArrSales` in the code but you do read twice into `ArrNames[count]`. A typo? Also, please show the *declaration* of both arrays.

Comment: You've just said the program compiles. That contradicts your question, which is about a compiler error. Please remain focused on *this* question. If you are no longer interested in the answer to this question, then delete it and post a new question about the current status of your code. This question is about code that doesn't compile.

Comment: Need it's definition, but that cahps are right, given you can't really know how many lines there are in the file one of the list classes is coing to work better.

Comment: @KMunro if declaring them in the procedure worked then the one outside, whatever it is not in scope.

Comment: @Tony, this is for a school assignment, where list classes (or *any* classes, for that matter) probably haven't been introduced yet. Trust that the instructor has provided guidance on how big an array should be to accommodate the input.

Comment: I have edited the question so that it looks like my unit... I don't know whether the problem lies in the procedure, or the button click event

Comment: Now you'll have to define "doesn't work".  The arrays end up with nothing in them?

Comment: More like the richedit ends up with nothing in it... So, I dont even know whether the text files have been read into the arrays.

Comment: How are you assigning the arrays to the richedit?

Comment: Does data.txt actually exist, and is it in the same directory as your program's executable file (Which is NOT necessarily the same as your source files). If not, specify a full path.

Comment: @NickHodges I fixed the richedit, and it compiles, but it crashes as soon as I click the button. It doesnt give me any error messages, just a warning that says "Variable 'J' might not have been initialized"

Comment: Looks like you posted fake code. Please don't ever do that.

Comment: The data.txt file is in the programs executable folder... All other textfile programs I have written work, but this is the first one that uses an array...

Comment: This is only Grade 11 school material though... I'm still learning...

Comment: @KMunro learning or not, but you should be able to copy'paste your original code

Comment: I don't understand... I working from a text book, and following as much of the instructions as necessary, but without error messages I don't know how to debug.

Comment: I pasted the whole code...

Comment: OK. You've pasted all the code. Good. Thank you. Is "invalid type cast" still the problem? If not, then change the question's title. An 11th grader should be able to recognize that "problems when compiling" is not a sufficient description. Be specific. If you're having a problem when compiling, then you need to *say* what that problem is. Quote the error message and indicate which line of code the error occurs on.

Comment: The only possible code which I see able to even execute (`btnShowDataClick`) isn't even calling the bulk of the code (`ShowData`). It's immediately reading from an array which doesn't appear to even be populated yet. So you have a form with a button. You click that button. All it does is one line of code `redt1.lines.add(aNames[J] +#9 + 'R' +IntToStr(aSales[J]));` which definitely will not work because none of the other code in your unit will actually do anything at all.

Answer (score 7):

Now having your *real code* I will list *some* of your mistakes:

- `ShowData` is never called
- `ShowData` is a bad name, because it **doesn't show anything** but only **reading data** from a file, so better rename it to `ReadData`
- `aNames` and `aSales` are **local** variables of the procedure `ShowData` / method `TForm1.btnShowDataClick` and the lifetime is only inside this procedure/method. You can't access to local variables of another procedure/method.

  Solution: Define them as private fields of `TForm1`

---

As a *minor* improvement you should name all types starting with `T` (e.g. `TMyType`). It's just a convention, but very helpful.

There are [a lot more of naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268441/what-does-fxxx-private-class-name-prefix-convention-came-from/14268873#14268873)

---

`If FileExists( 'data.txt' ) <> true`

is not wrong but bad and you should write it as in your mind "*If the file not exists, I will do something different*"

`if not FileExists( 'data.txt' )`

is much more readable (and stop headaches on several users ;o) )

---

Here is the complete unit with all the improvements and some comments in it.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls;

type
  TArrNames = array [1 .. 10] of string;
  TArrSales = array [1 .. 10] of integer;

type
  TForm1 = class( TForm )
    btnShowData : TButton;
    redt1 : TRichEdit;
    procedure btnShowDataClick( Sender : TObject );
  private
    // private fields of TForm1
    aNames : TArrNames;
    aSales : TArrSales;

    procedure ReadData;  // now it is a private method of TForm1
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  // procedure Showdata; -> renamed/moved to TForm1.ReadData

var
  Form1 : TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

// procedure Showdata;
procedure TForm1.ReadData;
var
  c2u :   textfile;
  count : integer;
  // aNames : ArrNames;
  // aSales : ArrSales;
Begin
  // If FileExists( 'data.txt' ) <> true
  // better
  if not FileExists( 'data.txt' )
  then
    begin
      MessageDlg( 'File does not exist', mtError, [mbOK], 0 );
      Exit;
    end;
  count := 0;
  AssignFile( c2u, 'data.txt' );
  Reset( c2u );
  while not EOF( c2u ) do
    begin
      Inc( count );
      ReadLn( c2u, aNames[count] );
      ReadLn( c2u, aSales[count] );
    end;
  CloseFile( c2u );
End;

procedure TForm1.btnShowDataClick( Sender : TObject );
var
  J : Integer;
  // aNames : ArrNames;
  // aSales : ArrSales;
begin
  // first, read the data
  ReadData;
  // loop over each array item
  for J := 1 to 10 do
    redt1.Lines.Add( aNames[J] + #9 + 'R' + IntToStr( aSales[J] ) );
end;

end.
```

Comment: And change the illogical ` If FileExists( 'data.txt' ) <> true then` to `if not FileExists('data.txt') then`. The double negatives and needless comparison with TRue hurts my head.

Comment: What happens if there are more than ten lines in the file? It would be better to move the entire 'ReadData' procedure into the button event handler, having the rich edit component be loaded directly from the file without those limited arrays.

Comment: @No'amNewman 1) The data inside the file has to be converted/interpreted for output. 2) This is an exercise for intermediates and one of the goals is array handling

Comment: Although I answered I also voted to close *as not a real question*. It could also have been closed for being *too localized*.

Comment: You actually figured out how the code was supposed to work and fixed it for him? Hats off to you Sir Rufo.