# Accessing new attributes/properties on building Inno-Setup from source?

Tags: delphi, inno-setup, delphi-2009

I've got a little problem with building Inno Setup from source. I want to modify the **TNewButton** type to put a little more functionality into the setup-buttons. For example I changed the type-declaration from

```
TNewButton = class(TButton)
protected
  procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
end;
```

to

```
TNewButton = class(TButton)
  procedure CMDialogChar( var Msg: TCMDialogChar); message cm_DialogChar;
private
  FNoShortcut : Boolean;
protected
  procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
public
  property NoShortcut : Boolean read FNoShortcut write FNoShortcut;
end;
```

So I created a private attribute *NoShort* that is accessed via the public property *NoShortcut* and is used in the procedure *CMDialogChar* (I want to disable in a specific situation, that the buttons ca be activated via shortcuts). There are some other things I want to implement, but they result in the same problem:

I can compile Inno Setup with these modifications without any problems (I use **Delphi 2009** to get unicode support) and am also able to create an installer. But when I try to access the new property *NoShortcut* in an .iss-file (e.g. "WizardForm.NextButton.NoShortcut := true;"), the Inno compiler stops with the error

```
Unknown Identifier 'NOSHORTCUT'
```

Do I have to register these new attributes and properties in a special way to use them in my iss-Files? Any help will be appreciated :D

Comment: You have to publish your new identifier for Pascal Script compiler and runtime engine. To be more specific, you'll have to modify `ScriptClasses_C.pas` file for compilation time and `ScriptClasses_R.pas` file for runtime.

Comment: Man, that was fast! And also the solution for my problem! That was the missing detail that I was looking for. I edited those two files accordingly and now everything works as expected. Once again you helped me a lot with your apparently huge Inno-knowledge :D (I am new to Stackoverflow, so how is now the usual procedure? Shall I write your solution as an answer and accept it to 'close' this thread?)

Comment: Yes, feel free to do so, if someone won't be faster ;-)

Comment: Just a **cosmetic** thing: you should name the private field fNoShortcut instead of NoShort. Then everyone will know, *fNoShortcut* is a *field* related to the property *NoShortcut*.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the hint. I am not so familiar with Delphi/Pascal naming conventions yet.

Comment: @SirRufo, to be pedantic; it should be `FNoShortcut` instead of `fNoShortcut` ;-)

Comment: @TLama I know :o) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268441/what-does-fxxx-private-class-name-prefix-convention-came-from/14268873#14268873

Comment: So, to use what I've just learned, I changed the formatting of the private field :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As TLama pointed out, the new identifier has to be registered in both `ScriptClasses_C.pas` and `ScriptClasses_R.pas`. To be a little more specific in matters of the question:

In `ScriptClasses_C.pas` I created a procedure `RegisterTNewButton_C` to let the compiler know about my new identifier for the button:

```
procedure RegisterTNewButton_C(Cl: TPSPascalCompiler);
begin
  with Cl.AddClassN(Cl.FindClass('TButton'), 'TNewButton') do
  begin
    RegisterProperty('NoShortcut', 'Boolean', iptrw);
  end;
end;
```

In `ScriptClasses_R.pas` I basically do the same, but I additionally had to implement to getter and setter for the new identifier:

```
procedure TNewButtonNoShortcut_R(Self: TNewButton; var T: Boolean); 
begin 
  T := Self.NoShortcut;
end;

procedure TNewButtonNoShortcut_W(Self: TNewButton; const T: Boolean); 
begin 
  Self.NoShortcut := T; 
end;

procedure RegisterTNewButton_R(CL: TPSRuntimeClassImporter);
begin
  with CL.Add(TNewButton) do
  begin
    RegisterPropertyHelper(@TNewButtonNoShortcut_R,@TNewButtonNoShortcut_W,'NoShortcut');
  end;
end;
```

To make it finally work `RegisterTNewButton_C` has to be called in the method `ScriptClassesLibraryRegister_C` and `RegisterTNewButton_R` in `ScriptClassesLibraryRegister_R` accordingly.

In addition I deleted/commented the lines that registered TNewButton previously (in `RegisterBidiCtrls_C` and in `RegisterBidiCtrls_R`) to avoid errors that could evolve when a component is registered twice. But I don't know if this is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting! I wanted to make the getter and setter look like to other ones in the code-file, but for the purpose of this answer, the standard formatting for procedures fits much better. :)